# Python NumPy: referencing columns

Tags: python, numpy

Why is `array1[:][1] != array1[:,1]` ?

For example:

```
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
array1[1] ## Output: array([4,5,6]) as expected
array1[:,1] ## Output: array([2, 5, 8]) as expected
array1[:][1] ## Output: array([4,5,6]) which isn't what I expected!
```

When using double bracket referencing, is the `array1[:]` component executed first returning the full `2D` array? Therefore `array1[:][1] == array1[1]`?

Comment: with `array1[:]` you are accessing copy of array1!! that's why both are same.. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy will interpret `a[:]` as a copy of the array instead of the set of 'rows'. Basic slicing is only analogous to successive slicing until `:` entries appear. From the docs (section 1.4 - Indexes):

> Basic slicing with more than one non-: entry in the slicing tuple, acts like repeated application of slicing using a single non-: entry, where the non-: entries are successively taken (with all other non-: entries replaced by :). Thus, `x[ind1,...,ind2,:]` acts like `x[ind1][...,ind2,:]` under basic slicing.

There is an implied complication when `:` entries get handled.